# Unidentified Symbols Returned from Server When Using Socket

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sockets

I wrote a basic code to read a line from a server and used `readline()` to see what will be the output.
But some unidentified symbols are being returned and I don't know what they are or why they are coming. I could use some help Thanks.
I've also provided a link to the photo of what is being returned.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AM27ZAKy4iJNJH8vpY1XGy-E0YAxZyNw/view?usp=sharing

This the code

```
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.14", 1099);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String data;
            if (socket.isConnected()) {
                data = reader.readLine();
                serverData.setText(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Could the server be sending objects or binary information?

Comment: They're coming because that's what's being sent. Looks like serialized data. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.